# Get element by tag not working?

Tags: javascript, css

Here is a very simple question, why get element by tag in javascript doesn't work like get element by id?

Here is my code example:

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/KvAfF

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("li").style.color="red";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements called [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Try the following:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].style.color="red";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a *collection of elements* (in a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)). To work on each element in this array, you can loop through the items.

whereas

`getElementById()` returns one DOMElement - which has `style` and other attributes.

Comment: @Ankit - Yeah, to be precise a NodeList. Edited to make it clearer. Tks,